# AnkiDroid: Change decks tts language

Tags: languages, text-to-speech, ankidroid

In my phone, Ankidroid ask me every time what language shall be used for each card side. Which is listed as a bug.

But with other phones (eg. Samsung S2 mini) opposite problem arises. Once you select TTS language for a particular deck there is no way to change it.

I reinstalled both, TTS engine and Ankidroid, but the TTS language setting is still there.

What should I do to force ankidroid to allow me to select another TTS language?

Phone: Samsung S6500 Galaxy Mini II
Ankidroid: 2.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In AnkiDroid preferences, there is a "Reset Languages" item:

> Reset language assignments (for text to speech and dictionaries) for all decks. Reset specific deck assignments on deck picker