# AnkiDroid: Reset TTS language of a single deck

Tags: languages, text-to-speech, ankidroid

I am not able to find the correct way to reset the TTS language of just one deck (as opposed to resetting all TTS assignments by using Menu > Preferences > General > Reset).
I have seen [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52194/ankidroid-change-decks-tts-language), but I can't work out what's meant by

> Reset specific deck assignments on deck picker

I am really feeling dumb right now... The "deck picker" is the list of "decks on the AnkiDroid "home screen" right? If so, where is the option to reset TTS for one deck?

I tried the menu by "long-pressing" on one item, but that just gave me the option to collapse, rename or delete the deck.

Opening one deck and then going to Menu > Preferences > General > Reset yields the same as going there from the "home screen", all assignments are reset.

I am lost, can anyone shed light on this for me?

Comment: The "deck picker" is the list of "decks on the AnkiDroid "home screen" right? ← Yes

Comment: Hm... and how can I reset the TTS assignments of one specific deck there? I can't find such an option...

Answer (score 0):

You can try resetting all the settings in the deck.

In 2018, there is a feature for setting TTS language for AnkiDroid starting at 2.6alpha6 (please edit if mistaken).